# Why doesn't my service default exception handler catch my service exceptions?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to catch all unhandled exceptions that occur in a service
that runs in a separate process. In the onCreate for the service, I call
a method that calls Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler with
MyCustomExceptionHandler class. My examination of the logs indicates
that it is set but does not consistently get called for uncaught
exceptions. For example, when I hard code a divide by zero into the
service, it does not get called at all. Another example is a
NullPointerException that I forced which resulted in a call to my
handler but the stack trace did not point to the actual lines of code
that caused the exception.

```
public class ActivityEngineService extends android.app.Service {

    /** Called when the service is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        setUncaughtExceptionHandler(); 

        // Get the service that has a hard coded divide by zero running  
    }

    public void setUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler());
        System.out.println("Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(): " + Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    }

    public class CustomExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

        public CustomExceptionHandler() {
            this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        }

        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("CustomExceptionHandler uncaughtException e: " + e.getMessage());
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I can't help but ask the question "would the exception have got thrown in a separate thread where the handler wasn't set?"

Comment: How you compile this? "new CustomExceptionHandler(appFilesDir)", you don't have constructor that fit that.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplify for the post and forgot to remove the parameter in the call. It should have been "new CustomExceptionHandler()". The compilation does work.

Comment: My understanding, asgs, was that the handler should catch exceptions from all threads.

Comment: After more testing, I have found that my CustomExceptionHandler is actually catching exceptions from both the main thread and from threads fired up manually. However, it does not catch exceptions that occur within the context of AIDL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html):

```
Sets the default uncaught exception handler. This handler is invoked in case any Thread dies due to an unhandled exception.
```

As far as I know in your case whole process is dying, that's why `uncaughtException` does not invoke. It will invoked if you will have uncaught exceptions inside separate threads.

Comment: Do you mean that a divide by zero can kill the whole process as opposed to just affecting the thread in which it occurs?

Comment: Of course, every uncaught exception killing process and VM dying too. This method will work only in manually created threads, not in main.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen threads die without bringing down the whole process.  You could test this by, after setting the default uncaught exception handler, firing up a new thread for the explicit purpose of throwing a runtime exception from inside it, and see if that brings down your service.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. Every uncaught exception inside main thread kill while VM, or possible you don't know that services run in main thread as well.